# Mount single file as volume to Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I am trying to run version latest tag of the image available at https://hub.docker.com/r/kernelmemory/service.

This image relies on a single file as configuration to run.

The example command to run it locally is:

`docker run --volume ./appsettings.Development.json:/app/appsettings.Production.json -it --rm -p 9001:9001 kernelmemory/service:1.0`

As you can see, it mounts the *appsettings.Development.json* file from the local host to *appsettings.Production.json* file on the Docker image.

Now, I want to deploy this image to Azure Container Apps. I have gone through various posts and documentation, but I couldn't find a way to mount a single file to Azure Container App, either during the deployment with Bicep or later.

Currently, I am using a FileShare as a mount.

Have you experienced this issue/limitation before? Do you have any possible workarounds or suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure Container Apps does not currently support mounting a single file as a volume. As you mentioned, the workaround is to use a FileShare as a mount. You can create a FileShare in Azure Storage and mount it as a volume in your container app. Then, you can upload your single file to the FileShare and access it from your container app.

Comment: References:

-   [Use storage mounts in Azure Container Apps (azure-portal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts?pivots=azure-portal#azure-files)
-   [Tutorial: Create an Azure Files volume mount in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts-azure-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting a single file as a volume in Azure Container Apps directly is not currently supported, as Azure Container Apps are designed to mount directories rather than individual files. However, as a workaround you can use an Azure File Share with your single file and mount it to your Azure Container App.

*Create an Azure File Share*

- Go to your storage account in the Azure portal.
- Navigate to "File shares" and create a new file share.
- Upload your `appsettings.Development.json` file to this file share.
  [image]

*Mount the File Share to your Container App*

When you set up your Azure Container App, you'll include the Azure File Share as a volume in the configuration. This can be done using  CLI

```
az containerapp create \
  --name <Container-App-Name> \
  --resource-group <Resource-Group-Name> \
  --image <Container-Image> \
  --environment <Environment-Name> \
  --secrets <Your-File-Share-Access-Key-Name>=<Your-File-Share-Access-Key> \
  --volume <Volume-Name>=<File-Share-Name>:<File-Share-Mount-Path>
```

or from portal at the time of creation or even later under container-> volume mounts

[image]

Note, you'll need to create a secret containing the access key for your storage account. This secret will be used by the Container App to authenticate with the Azure File Share.

```
az containerapp env secret set \
  --name <Environment-Name> \
  --resource-group <Resource-Group-Name> \
  --secret-file-share-name <Your-File-Share-Access-Key-Name>=<Your-File-Share-Access-Key>
```

or from portal, get the access key from storage account
[image]

and add it as a secret in your container app
[image]

References:

- [Use storage mounts in Azure Container Apps (azure-portal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts?pivots=azure-portal#azure-files)
- [Mount Azure Storage as a local share in App Service (container-windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows)
- [Tutorial: Create an Azure Files volume mount in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/storage-mounts-azure-files#create-the-storage-mount)

Comment: This does not fully answer my question. What I want to do is bind a single file to a file in the image repository. As mentioned: 
`./appsettings.Development.json:/app/appsettings.Production.json`

Comment: I understand your ask. In environments like Docker, you can directly mount a single file from the host to the container. However, Azure Container Apps currently lacks the capability to directly mount a single file from an Azure File Share into a container. The platform supports mounting volumes at the directory level but not individual files. As a workaround, you can use an initialization script or modify your application to read the appsettings.Development.json from the mounted directory instead of directly from /app/appsettings.Production.json.

Comment: And if going with an init script option then while deploying the container, mount the File Share at a directory (e.g., /mnt) and let the init script handle the placement of the appsettings.Development.json file which will mount the File Share at /mnt, and upon container startup, the init.sh script will copy appsettings.Development.json from /mnt to /app/appsettings.Production.json but yes this too  isn't a direct bind mount.